# Как задать размеры TextView размерами background?

Tags: android

можно ли переоределить класс TextView так чтоб ширина и высота элемента были равны исходным размерам фонового изображения?

(требуется сохранить исходные размеры изображения, а текст расположить в его центре)

Comment: Используете в `ImageWiew` высоту и ширину как `wrap_content`. А текст по центру с помощью `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если так сделать:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```